# AUMIDIEffectBase, error validating plugin

Tags: audio, core-audio, units-of-measurement

I have just converted the Filter AU example from apple to use AUMIDIEffectBase class in order to convert it to midi controlled effect.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/FilterDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

The filter builds however I am getting error in auval tool:

Test MIDI
ERROR: -4 IN CALL MusicDeviceSendMIDI

Anybody has implemented AUMIDIEffectBase successfully?
Any example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem today and discovered the issue is in a slightly non-current release of Apple's CoreAudioUtilityClasses, AUMIDIEffectBase class.  Due to multiple inheritance the following needed to be added to AUMIDIEffectBase.h so that AUPluginDispatch calls the correct overridden methods.

```
virtual OSStatus    MIDIEvent(      UInt32                      inStatus, 
                                    UInt32                      inData1, 
                                    UInt32                      inData2, 
                                    UInt32                      inOffsetSampleFrame)
{
    return AUMIDIBase::MIDIEvent (inStatus, inData1, inData2, inOffsetSampleFrame);
}

/*! @method SysEx */
virtual OSStatus    SysEx(          const UInt8 *               inData, 
                                    UInt32                      inLength) 
{
    return AUMIDIBase::SysEx (inData, inLength);
}
```

I just pulled the latest from Apple's site: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/CoreAudioUtilityClasses.zip  and it looks like they already fixed the issue.  We both had bad download timing, it seems!